Bound ripple effect to parent composable
I have a custom BottomBar with typical tabs as children and addition views that needs the full bar's width and that are placed depending on the tabs height.
Because of that, the tabs' height is not the full height, and the ripple effect is bounded to this tab height. When I unbound the ripple effect, it goes outside the limit of the BottomBar.
Is there a way to bound the ripple effect to the parent of the clickable area, so that it limits itself in the height of the BottomBar?
Here is the unbounded version of the BottomBar:
@Composable
fun BottomBar(
    items: List<BottomBarItem>,
    onItemSelected: (Int) -> Unit,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .defaultMinSize(68.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = Color.Blue),
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 68.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            ) {
                items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                            .clickable(
                                onClick = { onItemSelected(index) },
                                indication = ripple(bounded = false, color = Color.Red),
                                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                            ),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                    ) {
                        Text(text = item.label, color = Color.White)
                    }
                }
            }
            // Other views with full width this placed directly below the tabs content...
        }
    }
}


You can use Modifer.clipToBounds() which is graphicsLayer(clip = true) on outer Box inside BottomBar which will clip anything drawn out of Box bounds. You can also use Modifier.graphicslayer{clip = true}
